# Weighted center of mass of an image, using the correct weights

Tags: optics, visible-light

I have an RGB picture that I transform in grayscale. I then find the weighted center of mass but the problem is that the weights are:

> $Y = 0.2125 R + 0.7154 G + 0.0721 B$

Calibrated for contemporary CRT phosphors.

I have a simple intensity picture where red signifies it has more intensity, yellow less, green even less, and blue much less.

How can I correctly change the weights to reflect this?

Comment: You need to know which colormap was used to plot your RGB picture. It is the only way to know the exact coefficients that are needed to change to a correct grayscale and to calculate the real center of mass.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I follow your question.

Typically, the three coefficients are determined by the properties of a standard eye. Y is the intensity of a grayscale color that would look equally bright as that RGB color. It is used to make a grayscale image look as much as possible like a color image.

Are you saying that you want to calculate the intensity of an equivalent grayscale image generated from a color image based on 4 colors? If so, you will need to make a lot of measurements to determine how intense each color appears to many people. You will need to average to figure out how sensitive an average observer is to each.

Or are you saying you want to make a false color image where color represents how bright a colored pixel would appear to an average observer? That is much easier. Y represents how bright a pixel would appear. Set threshold intensities for brightness that you would paint each false color. When you generate the image, instead of creating a grayscale pixel, generate on of the 4 false colors.

Or are you trying to calculate the position of the centroid of an image with a weighted average of all the pixels? In that case,

$$\vec r_{cent} = \frac{\sum_i \vec r_i Y_i}{\sum_i Y_i}$$

where $\vec r_i$ is the position of the $i^{th}$ pixel.

---

Edit: Corrected the weighted average, as StephenG had it right.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct any weighted average as :

$$\bar{X}=\frac{\sum w_ix_i}{\sum w_i}$$

You are free to use any values of $w_i$ (the weights) you like for each component ($x_i$) so long as $\sum w_i \ne 0$ to avoid division by zero.